# Show that absorbing and convex set contains Hamel basis

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-hulls, hamel-basis

Show that absorbing and convex set contains Hamel basis.

I know the definitons of convexity and being absorbing. Also, I know that every vector space has Hamel basis, but these are all informations I received from lecture. So my first thought was to trying to show that indeed absorbing convex set forms a vector space. Is it even true? If so, I would be glad for any hints.

Comment: Absorbing sets and convex sets are subsets of some given vector space. What they want you to prove is that if a set is both absorbing and convex, then you can pick a Hamel basis for the entire vector space from the elements of that set. The is no need for the set itself to be a vector subspace. In fact, if it were a subspace, it would have to be the entire vector space since any subset of it could not span more than that subspace.

Comment: As a hint, pick an arbitrary Hamel basis for the vector space, then contemplate on what the definition of absorbing says about this basis and the set.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I will try it myself, but still I have a question about usefulness of convexity. Where should it be used? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have the same question. I have no idea why they tacked convexity on this problem.